# Postgres - How to automatically call ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat), 4326) on inserts?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgis

I'm using postGIS, and I'm not very familiar with SQL.

I can successfully insert into my `markers` table as long as I do something like this (*pseudocode!)*:

```
'INSERT INTO markers(created_by, title, description, lat, lng, geography)\
       values($1, $2, $3, $4::decimal, $5::decimal, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($5::decimal, $4::decimal), $6))',
      [
        data.created_by,
        data.title,
        data.description,
        data.lat,
        data.lng,
        4326
      ]'
```

As you can see, I am doing `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($5::decimal, $4::decimal), $6)` from my application code.

I want to avoid that, and instead put this on the database side.  Since I can do things like auto time stamps on the db side, I'm wondering if I can also do `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat), 4326)` on the table itself.

This way, the application only needs to provide lat and lng, and the database will do the `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint())` operation.

Thanks

Edit: I'm not sure whose answer to mark as +1 since both offered tremendously good help and advice.  I hope future readers will read both and hopefully learn something!

Comment: paste the result of `\d markers`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using a trigger. Your insert call would not deal with the geometry, only with lat-long and other non-spatial fields, and the trigger function will create the geometry. Let's not forget to do the same when updating the row.
Note that I have hard-coded the SRID as it is not possible to pass extra dynamic parameters to the trigger function. If need be, add a field to your table to hold this value and you can refer to it as `new.srid`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION markers_geog_tg_fn() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' AND (NEW.lat ISNULL or NEW.lng ISNULL  ) THEN
    RETURN NEW; -- no  geometry
  ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
    --Lat Long updated to null, erase geometry
    IF NEW.lat ISNULL or NEW.lng ISNULL THEN
        NEW.geography = NULL;
    END IF;

    IF NEW.lat IS NOT DISTINCT FROM OLD.lat and NEW.lng IS NOT DISTINCT FROM OLD.lng THEN
      RETURN NEW; -- same old geometry
    END IF;
  END IF;
  -- Attempt to transform a geometry
  BEGIN
    NEW.geography := ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(NEW.lng::decimal, NEW.lat::decimal), 4326))
  EXCEPTION WHEN SQLSTATE 'XX000' THEN
    RAISE WARNING 'geography  not updated: %', SQLERRM;
  END;
  RETURN NEW;
END;$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER markers_geog_tg BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON markers FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE markers_geog_tg_fn();
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to avoid that, and instead put this on the database side. Since I can do things like auto time stamps on the db side, I'm wondering if I can also do `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat), 4326)` on the table itself.

It's *really* not a good idea, I know it sounds like a good idea though and seems appealing. That said, you're doing more work than you need to do.

```
CREATE TABLE markers (geom geography(POINT,4326) );
INSERT INTO markers(geom) VALUES (ST_MakePoint(0,0));
```

As you can see here, `geography` has a default SRID of 4326. You don't have to set it to 4326, though being explicit doesn't hurt. Moreover, casting the input to `ST_MakePoint()` to decimal is a *bad* idea. `ST_MakePoint` only accepts `double precision`. Result from `\df ST_MakePoint`

```
                                                     List of functions
 Schema |     Name     | Result data type |                          Argument data types                           |  Type  
--------+--------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------
 public | st_makepoint | geometry         | double precision, double precision                                     | normal
 public | st_makepoint | geometry         | double precision, double precision, double precision                   | normal
 public | st_makepoint | geometry         | double precision, double precision, double precision, double precision | normal
```

So you can see here you extra cast is actually just adding more work. What you really want is just the simple `ST_MakePoint(lng,lat)` into a `geography(POINT,4326)` column.

The rest of the task requires a trigger. It would also require having an extra column lat and long. **While I can tell you *how* to do it, I would highly suggest *not* doing it.**

```
ALTER TABLE markers
  ADD COLUMN lat double precision,
  ADD COLUMN long double precision;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_stupid_stuff()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
  BEGIN
    NEW.geom = ST_MakePoint(NEW.long, NEW.lat);
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER really_lazy
  AFTER INSERT ON markers
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE do_stupid_stuff();
```

Comment: Thanks!  Can you please expand on why I should not do it?  I understand the issue with using decimal - I will take a look into it, but I believe I am doing this because I get the lat lng from the client side as a string.

Comment: Explain why you should not do what? Use ::decimal, if you get it form the client as a string -- numify it *before* you send it to the server. Don't send it to the server as a string and ask Pg to numify it (it's just slower and uglier that way).

Comment: sorry I meant the trigger.  Why not to use it?  Thank you!

Comment: As to why you should not use `ST_MakePoint` in a trigger like that, because it's not the way SQL works. You're trying to save a point in the database, you should construct the point. What if in the future rather than coming from lat/long you want it to come from geojson, wkt, wkb, kml, gml, or geohash? You shouldn't put that logic in the server. You're setting a point -- how you construct a point doesn't go there. What do you gain? Hiding the call to `ST_MakePoint()`? That's like 15 characters.

Comment: I see, thanks!  Please if you don't mind - what are some common use cases for triggers?

Comment: @scarywolfman triggers are *great* if you need to validate something, especially when the data is not normalized. For instance, if you're taking points that represent locations and you want to me sure those points reside in polygons associated with specific names or the like. Think check constraints that reference others tables in more complex conditions than can be done with fkeys.