# How can I calculate locationGeo space in pgadmin 3 type with PostGIS functions?

Tags: postgis, rails-postgresql

My table name is `map` and I have `latitude(double),longitude(double)` and `locationGeo(geometry)` columns. I want to use a function to automatically compute the `LocationGeo` value using the given latitude and longitude values when I save a record. That's my wanted format:

> Point(latitude,longitude),SRID

I can't find documentation for it in web.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the default value is not the adequate way. What if you insert a record with no latitude or longitude? Instead you should either construct the geometry when you insert it, or make use of a [trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47492820/7635569) to make validation and compute it for you.